# Fulfillment_created_at ror3 shopify api error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, shopify

How to use arrays and get order date?

I get the date when the order was shipped.( order.line_items_line_item.fulfillment.created_at)

Help plz thx

I'm doing this

## controller

### @order   = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all)

## views   -work

```
    <% @order.each do |order|  %>
        <span class="highlight"><%= order.customer.email %></span>

    <%= order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>

           <span class="note"><% line_item.title %></span>

    <% end %>

    <% end %>

    </ul>

  <% end %>
```

## views   -don't work

```
    <% @order.each do |order|  %>

    <%= order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
           <span class="note"><% line_item.created_at %></span>

    <% end %>

    <% end %>

    </ul>

  <% end %>
```

## views   -don't work

```
<% if @order.line_items %>
      <% @order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
        <tr>       
          <td><%= line_item.created_at %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understand your question, but if you’re looking for when an order was created, you want

```
@order.created_at
```

Take a look at the JSON responses in http://api.shopify.com/order.html or do a

```
puts @order.inspect
```

to see what kind of data comes back from an Order API call.

Comment: Edward Thanks for response. I need date when order was fulfilled with format date 02.11.2011

Answer (score 0):

Line items don't have a `created_at` field, they're properties of the order in the same way that adress lines are part of an address.

There's a separate object that deals with order fulfillments. Here's the page on the docs: http://api.shopify.com/fulfillment.html

Using the ruby gem you can just call `order.fulfillments` to get an array of fulfillments. Then you can loop over those to see when the line items were fulfilled.